# .NET MVC2 - My area url does not register?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a new MVC-2 project where I added the area 'member'. I created a controller named: 'profile'.

This works: http://localhost:1234/Profile   (loads up the index() function)
This however doesn't: http://localhost:1234/Member/Profile (i get a 404 error)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for this not working. From the default project template:

1. Right click on the project Add -> Area : `Member`
2. In  `~/Areas/Member/Controllers` add `ProfileController` containing a default `Index` action
3. In `~/Areas/Member/Views/Profile` add `Index.aspx`
4. Run the application and navigate to `/member/profile` => it shows the newly added page

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your Global.asax.cs file, see whether it has the following code in Application_Start

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Answer (score 1):

If `http://localhost:1234/Profile` works, you might need to check the namespace of your `ProfileController`.  It should be:

```
namespace YourProjectName.Areas.Member
```